# rails 3: https redirect, but only for one specific domain name (or several)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, https

My app has user-facing and public-facing pages which are accessd via different subdomains user.example.com and public.example.com

I have a ssl cert for user.example.com and it all works fine when the user comes in via https.

And I know how to redirect to https for ANY domain used by my app, but not for ONE specific domain.

However, if someone comes in on http://user.example.com I'd like to redirect to https://user.example.com without doing nay special redirect for other subdomains (or domains) they might come in on.

Is there a way in rails to redirect to https all requests that come on one specific subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to do this is in your web server (e.g. Apache, nginx, etc.) configuration. If you don't have access to that, then write a before_filter in ApplicationController that compares against `request.host` and `request.ssl?` e.g.:

```
def redirect_user_subdomain_to_https
  if 'user.example.com' == request.host && !request.ssl?
    redirect_to request.url.gsub(/^http/, 'https')
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: that looks interesting, thanks. I'm on heroku so no, dont have access to the web server config. will give that a try, thanks!

Comment: I am using this basic method on a heroku app just fine.